# how to hide a div in first loop and keep showing in others

Tags: php

i have a php loop in my view, that i am showing data from database. i want to disable one div that has citizenship class in first loop and in next all loops it should show, how to do this?

```
 <?php 
 $i = 1;
foreach($appdetails2 as $appdetails2n){ ?>

 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-5 text-md-right text-sm-right" data-xtr-key="Passport number">Passport Expiry</div>
 <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-7"><strong><?php echo $appdetails2n['ped'];?></strong></div>
</div>

<!-- to be hidden in first loop-->   


<div class="row citizenship">
 <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-5 text-md-right text-sm-right" data-xtr-key="Citizenship">Citizenship</div>
<div class="col-md-7 col-xs-7"><strong><?php echo $appdetails2n['citizenship'];?></strong></div>
</div>


</div>

 <br>
<?php } ?>
```

i have tried this but its not working.

```
<div class="row citizenship" <?php if ($appdetails2n['citizenship']===NULL){?>style="display:none"<?php } ?>>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-5 text-md-right text-sm-right" data-xtr-key="Citizenship">Citizenship</div>
<div class="col-md-7 col-xs-7"><strong><?php echo $appdetails2n['citizenship'];?></strong></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Basic logic is: if something is equal (or not) to something, do something.

Comment: in the first loop, <?php echo $appdetails2n['citizenship'];?> is empty, because information about the master person is entered in another table already. it is being shown separately.

Answer (score 0):

```
  TRY 

<?php 
 $i =0;
 foreach($appdetails2 as $appdetails2n) { ?>
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-5 text-md-right text-sm-right" data-xtr-key="Passport number">Passport Expiry</div>
     <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-7"><strong><?php echo $appdetails2n['ped'];?></strong></div>
    </div>

    <!-- to be hidden in first loop-->   
    <?php
    if($i>0)
    { ?>
    <div class="row citizenship">
     <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-5 text-md-right text-sm-right" data-xtr-key="Citizenship">Citizenship</div>
    <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-7"><strong><?php echo $appdetails2n['citizenship'];?></strong>
</div>
   </div>
    </div>
     <?php } ?>
     <br>
    <?php $i=$i+1; } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<?php 
  $i = 1;
  foreach($appdetails2 as $appdetails2n) { ?>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-5 text-md-right text-sm-right" data-xtr-key="Passport number">Passport Expiry</div>
      <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-7"><strong><?php echo $appdetails2n['ped'];?></strong></div>
    </div>

    <!-- to be hidden in first loop-->   
    <?php if($i !== 1) { ?>
    <div class="row citizenship">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-5 text-md-right text-sm-right" data-xtr-key="Citizenship">Citizenship</div>
     <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-7"><strong><?php echo $appdetails2n['citizenship'];?></strong></div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <br>
<?php $i++; } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $first_key = array_key_first($appdetails2);
    foreach($appdetails2 as $key => $appdetails2n) { ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-5 text-md-right text-sm-right" data-xtr-key="Passport number">Passport Expiry</div>
            <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-7"><strong><?php echo $appdetails2n['ped'];?></strong></div>
        </div>

        <!-- to be hidden in first loop-->   
        <?php if($key != $first_key) { ?>
        <div class="row citizenship">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-5 text-md-right text-sm-right" data-xtr-key="Citizenship">Citizenship</div>
            <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-7"><strong><?php echo $appdetails2n['citizenship'];?></strong></div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
     <?php } ?>
     <br>
```

You can also set display none with that condition!